# Git - Wrong behavior when merging in branch master

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I have the following problem:

I have three branches releases that were merged consecutively in the master branch.

```
-> branch 'release/0.1.0'
    85a8e9a Merge branch 'BNP-157' into develop
        8fc8c14 Fix and refine code.

# This branch was created from the develop until the "Merge branch 'BNP-157' into develop" on it.

-> branch 'release/0.2.0'
    a5820d2 Merge branch 'BNP-158' into develop
        4ae704b Remove letter_color choice to have a blue color as default.
    85a8e9a Merge branch 'BNP-157' into develop
        8fc8c14 Fix and refine code.

# This branch was created from the develop until the "Merge branch 'BNP-158' into develop" on it.


-> branch 'release/0.2.1'
    6a0ec11 Merge branch 'BNP-160' into develop
        14c24c3 Correct too long error
    c689817 Merge branch 'BNP-159' into develop
        2a8a5d9 Correct tax problem
    a5820d2 Merge branch 'BNP-158' into develop
        4ae704b Remove letter_color choice to have a blue color as default.
    85a8e9a Merge branch 'BNP-157' into develop
        8fc8c14 Fix and refine code.
```

All branches was merged with 'git merge --no-ff release/x.x.x' command in the master. So, before the problem, I expected the master timeline like this:

```
# TIMELINE A

f13b8ba Merge branch 'release/0.2.1'
    6a0ec11 Merge branch 'BNP-160' into develop
        14c24c3 Correct too long error
    c689817 Merge branch 'BNP-159' into develop
        2a8a5d9 Correct tax problem

efb8bc0 Merge branch 'release/0.2.0'
    a5820d2 Merge branch 'BNP-158' into develop
        4ae704b Remove letter_color choice to have a blue color as default.

01ae94e Merge branch 'release/0.1.0'
    85a8e9a Merge branch 'BNP-157' into develop
        8fc8c14 Fix and refine code.
```

However, I got instead of it the following timeline:

```
# TIMELINE B

f13b8ba Merge branch 'release/0.2.1'
    efb8bc0 Merge branch 'release/0.2.0'
        01ae94e Merge branch 'release/0.1.0'

            6a0ec11 Merge branch 'BNP-160' into develop
                14c24c3 Correct too long error

            c689817 Merge branch 'BNP-159' into develop
                2a8a5d9 Correct tax problem

            a5820d2 Merge branch 'BNP-158' into develop
                4ae704b Remove letter_color choice to have a blue color as default.

            85a8e9a Merge branch 'BNP-157' into develop
                8fc8c14 Fix and refine code.
```

Git put the release merges in the final of the timeline instead of merging like the TIMELINE A.

Could someone help with this problem?

This behavior is messing up the timeline of the master in the company where I work.

Comment: What do you mean by *timeline?* Git is more concerned with commit graph topology than with timestamps on commits; timestamps are just there for mere humans to interpret as they will. :-)

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was how the log is showed. The order that the commits are presented, its tree.

Comment: OK, well, that mainly depends on your *viewer*. Most Git commit viewers insist on presenting commits in some sort of linearized order. The general problem itself is hard (see https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/14901 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing for some introductory bits to some ideas here) and most programs just do something simple. The `git log` command itself offers 4 layouts: default, `--topo-order`, and two variations on `--topo-order`. It's important to realize that any of these 4 is just an approximation, and that there is only a *partial* order anyway.